# Jquery: How to select :first-child with :not(class)

Tags: jquery

I would like to select first occurrence of `li` from an `ul` which is not having particular class.

Check below snippet for example, Here I wanted add class `red` to first `li` which is not having class `myClass`. Here am expecting `<li>Two</li>` should add class `red`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul li:not(.myClass):first-child').addClass('red');
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="myClass">One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

**Update:** In same way I wanted to select second-child as well. Is it possible?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) instead of `:first-child` selector

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul li:not(.myClass):first').addClass('red');
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="myClass">One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

You can target element based on index using [`.eq(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

```
$('ul li:not(.myClass):eq(1)').addClass('red');
```

Comment: small information note: `:first` is specific to jQuery, it's not a CSS selector, and will influence the previous selected items. `:first-child` works differently, so that `li:first-child:not(.myClass)` wouldn't work either.

Comment: @ChitaB not the second child, am asking about second-child which does not have class `myClass`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `:first` instead of using `:first-child`. So your selector should like `'ul li:not(.myClass):first'`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul li:not(.myClass):first').addClass('red');
});
```

**Eidted**

After your comment, I would like to recommend jquery [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) function. By using eq() you can select any `li` by passing nth number of `li`.

```
$('ul li:not(.myClass):eq(1)').addClass('red');
```

For `eq()` function first position of `li` is `0`

Comment: It's working fine. Is there any way to select second-child as well?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul li:first-child').addClass('red');
});
```